# Arduino: Serial.find(char) not working

Tags: c++, stream, serial-port, arduino

Firstly, setup: Arduino IDE 1.5.7 beta, Nano v3.0

In short, my goal: use Serial.find() to wait for both standard EOL characters (both ASCII 13, CR, and ASCII 10, NL) to be found in the serial buffer, before proceeding with the following code.

my (problematic/shortened) code:

```
char charCr = 13;
char charNl = 10;

void loop(){
    do_stuff; 
    foo(); 
    do_other_stuff;}

void foo() 
{
      while (true)
      {
          if (Serial.find(bar1) && Serial.find(bar2))
          {
              break; // EOL characters found
          }
          delay(1); // wait to receive EOL
      }; 
}
```

OK, so two separate problems with what goes in `bar1` and `bar2`

If the `bars` are respectively `charCr` and `charNl` then the code doesn't compile whilst complaining:

```
error: call of overloaded 'find(char&)' is ambiguous
note: candidates are:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.h:29:0,
from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:221
```

finds a near match, which, I believe is the correct definition of find, as `Serial` inhereits it from `Stream`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Stream.h:59:8: note: bool Stream::find(char*) <near match>
bool find(char *target);   // reads data from the stream until the target string is found
```

But then also complains the char input should be a pointer (char*):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Stream.h:59:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'char' to 'char*'
```

The documentation I've read on Serial.find() and Stream.find() suggests that char should *not* be a pointer, just to pass the char value. Regardless, if `bar1` and `bar2` are referenced as `&charCr` and `&charNl` the code compiles fine, but the conditional is never met, and I know that I am sending both EOL characters, as confirmed by different means and debugging code.

So... what's going wrong with my code?

Comment: From comment: 'reads data from the stream until the target STRING is found' ie.  not char, string, which is why it is asking for pointers.

Comment: yes, but it also says for input data type "target : the string to search for (char)"... so what would be the proper syntax? and why, when I use the reference operator & does it not find it?

Comment: Try it - search for a null-terminated CR/LF string, see if that works.  If in doubt, suspect the documentation, (especially if I wrote it:).

Comment: OK, will try it, but pardon my naivety, I'm not an expert in C++, what's the syntax to define a null-terminated CR/LF string?

Comment: it seems that "char crlfnl[3] = {13, 10, 0};" might work, still working out the bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on the website is misleading because they say **string** but the function prototype is (char).  A **string** is a variable length character array.  A **char** is a single character.  When in doubt, always believe the function declaration in the header file (.H).  From Stream.h:

```
bool find(char *target);   // reads data from the stream until the target string is found
// returns true if target string is found, false if timed out (see setTimeout)

bool find(char *target, size_t length);   // reads data from the stream until the target string of given length is found
// returns true if target string is found, false if timed out
```

With those in mind, there are two ways forward.  Search single characters:

```
// method as you started - accepts terminators in either order
char charCr = 13;
char charNl = 10;

if (Serial.find(&charCr, 1) && Serial.find(&charNl, 1))
```

or string form:

```
char termseq1[] = {13, 10, 0};
char termseq2[] = {10, 13, 0};

if (Serial.find(termseq1) || Serial.find(termseq2))
```

Comment: This is true, also mentioned in comments to my OP with Martin James. Disappointing in other respects, however, because I believe Serial.find() works in a buffer-destructive manner such as Serial.read(), and not Serial.peek()... I was hoping to wait for EOL following an integer that is to be received, then use Serial.parseInt() to get it. Seems I'll have to work out another solution. Thanks